# Multiple identical messages with logstash/kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

I'm running an ELK stack on my local filesystem. I have the following configuration file set up:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/rfc5424"
    type => "RFC"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424LINE}" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  }
}
```

I have a kibana instance running as well. I write a line to `/var/log/rfc5424`:

```
$ echo '<11>1' "$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')" 'test-machine test-tag f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6 log [nsId orgID="12 \"hey\" 345" projectID="2345[hehe]6"] this is a test message' >> /var/log/rfc5424
```

And it shows up in Kibana. Great! However, weirdly, it shows up *six times*:

[image: why is it showing this many times?]

As far as I can tell everything about these message is identical, and I only have one instance of logstash/kibana running, so I have no idea what could be causing this duplication.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out if there is .swp or .tmp file for your configuration under conf directory.
2. Add document id to documents:

   ```
   output {
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
           document_id => "%{uuid_field}"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I check that there aren't any extra files in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` and added the document_id thing and it's still showing duplicates in kibana :(

Comment: What are you adding as document_id? As I can see the uuid field is same for duplicate instances.

Comment: I tried adding the message as the document id, and then I noticed that the messages differ by the number of repeats of the *actual* message that there are.